# How to create a button that colors a selected piece of text in a cell?

Tags: front-end, notebooks

I use *Mathematica* 9.0.1 and I want change the color of a selection in a **text** cell using a button. But when I use this code it changes the color of the entire cell.

```
Row[Button[Graphics[{#, Rectangle[]}, ImageSize -> 20], 
SetOptions[NotebookSelection[InputNotebook[]], FontColor -> #], Appearance -> None] & /@ 
   {ColorData["HTML"]["RoyalBlue"], ColorData["HTML"]["OliveDrab"],
    RGBColor[0.419608, 0, 0.733333], Black}]
```

What do I do wrong? It used to work in *Mathematica* 8 and 9.0.0. I want it to work **exactly like the Text Color command in the Writing Assistant palette** (or the **Format >> Text Color** menu command).

Comment: Where are the words in your example which should be colored? Perhaps you add a picture to your question and a picture of the desired output - this would be helpful, at least for me.

Comment: To be specific i would like to create a button which will color any kind of text.Not the entire cell but only the part which i choose with the mouse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CurrentValue` seems to be needed, then it works:

```
    Row[Button[Graphics[{#,Rectangle[]},ImageSize->20],
    CurrentValue[NotebookSelection[InputNotebook[]],FontColor]=#,
    Appearance->None]&/@{ColorData["HTML"]["RoyalBlue"],
    ColorData["HTML"]["OliveDrab"],RGBColor[0.419608,0,0.733333],Black}]
```

Comment: It seems to work fine in Mathematica 9.0.1!

Answer (score 3):

I don't have v9 to test, but perhaps this?

```
Button["red", FrontEndTokenExecute[InputNotebook[], FontColor, Red]]
```

Comment: Works for me too!

Answer (score 0):

The following

```
Cell[TextData[{"This is some example text in ", 
StyleBox["blue", FontColor->RGBColor[0, 0, 1]]}], 
"Text",CellChangeTimes->{{3.57440047356804*^9, 3.574400478269321*^9}}]
```

will result in

[image: Example Text with some part in blue]

Check out the Writing Assistant Palette. There you can find a lot of formatting options.

Comment: Pardon me but if I paste this literally, it won't produce the desired cell output. One has to wrap it in `CellPrint`. Also, `CellChangeTimes` is unncessary.

Comment: @IstvánZachar You're right. Thanks for the correction. I just copied the output of the formated cell using _CMD_ + _Shift_ + _E_.